# How to connect to Sharepoint files directory via some software resembling WinSCP or SmartFTP

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I need to download around 2000 files from a Sharepoint website and it is gonna take me ages to do that by downloading files one by one when I connect to website via some web browser...

I would prefer to use something like Total commander, WinSCP or SmartFTP...
This is the address of Sharepoint website:

http://ecampus.ucn.dk/my-ecampus/classsites/pswMaterial/SitePages/Home.aspx

Should I also write the credentials, so that you try to connect to it?
;-) I can change the password anytime...

If it was possible to map the Sharepoint directory to my laptop as a network drive, it would also be a solution...

Thank you very much !!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can map a SharePoint library to a network drive quite easily.  I'm guessing that you're using a publishing site or a team site with those features activated.

- In your URL, knock off the home.aspx to leave you with http://ecampus.ucn.dk/my-ecampus/classsites/pswMaterial/SitePages/
- In your desktop press Windows Key and E to bring up the Windows Explorer
- Press Alt to bring up the menu bar and head for Tools --> Map Network Drive.  This brings up a new dialog box.
- In this box, select the Drive letter and then post the URL from the first step on.  All other options should remain as is
- The box will close and you'll see the document library listed on the available destinations on the left of the Windows Explorer

Hope that makes sense, please let us know if not.

Comment: when i am mapping the drive should i tick off the option: using differnt credentials as well as reconnect as logon?

Comment: Depends whether you are on a domain and you use your currently logged in credentials to authenticate against the SharePoint site in question. Or if you have different credentials for SharePoint...

Comment: i have different credentials, i ticked it off and it doesn't work... i connect somehow but i can't get to files... i only see a directory Home and directory How to use this library

Comment: SharePoint has a built in "Open With Explorer" button that (if you are Windows) will open your desired folder in Explorer - without having to do any additional mapping. The "Open With Explorer" works on almost any Windows computer - regardless of whether you are on a domain computer or at home.

Comment: Open your SharePoint and go to the document library where your files are -> Whilst in the library (at the top) click "Library" tab -> Look around the icons displayed in the "ribbon" and you will see a buttone labelled "Open with Explorer".

Comment: i cannot click on Library tab... most probably i dont have a permission to do that...  you mean i should do that while i am connected to sharepoint via browser?

Comment: maybe the problem is in the address . for example this is tha address that i see when i get to one directory: http://ecampus.ucn.dk/my-ecampus/classsites/pswMaterial/SitePages/Home.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fmy-ecampus%2Fclasssites%2FpswMaterial%2FShared%20Documents%2FContract-based%20Software%20Development%2Fsession15&FolderCTID=0x0120005E7B29302F197A4AB76DC500F7FCF6E5&View={8750F148-CCBC-4DED-90A4-253FF107BECA}&InitialTabId=Ribbon.WikiPageTab&VisibilityContext=WSSTabPersistence

Comment: maybe this is the address i have to use when mapping: http://ecampus.ucn.dk/my-ecampus/classsites/pswMaterial/Shared Documents/Forms/

Comment: one of the directories has this address: http://ecampus.ucn.dk/my-ecampus/classsites/pswMaterial/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fmy%2Decampus%2Fclasssites%2FpswMaterial%2FShared%20Documents%2FContract%2Dbased%20Software%20Development&FolderCTID=0x0120005E7B29302F197A4AB76DC500F7FCF6E5&View={C14B2BAC-EBE5-44B5-8EDA-8BA45B581548}

Comment: they use differeent addresses, that's why...

Comment: HEUREKA, after 4 months i was able to connect !!!!!!!  ;-)